# How do I run saxon xslt transformation in java with parameters

Tags: java, xslt, xslt-1.0, saxon

I need to run this commandline arugment in a java file

```
java -jar output.docbook -o:output.fo -xsl:third_party\docbook_xsl\1_78_1\fo\docbook_FCRR.xsl axf.extensions=1 use.extensions=1
```

but what I'm trying isn't working. Here's what I have so far

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

try {
  // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
  Transformer transformer =
      tfactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslPath));
  transformer.setParameter("axf.extensions","1");
  transformer.setParameter("use.extensions","1");

  // Transform the source XML to System.out.
  transformer.transform(new StreamSource("output.docbook"),
      new StreamResult(new File("output.fo")));
}catch(TransformerException e){
  e.printStackTrace();

}
```

The command line code works fine but the java code is not.

> ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'insertCallouts' is not a valid object reference.'
>
> FATAL ERROR:  'The first argument to the non-static Java function 'insertCallouts' is not a valid object reference.'
>
> javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: The first argument to the non-static Java function 'insertCallouts' is not a valid object reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing comes from Xalan, not from Saxon.

Using the JAXP method `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` is pretty dangerous, because the XSLT processor you get depends purely on what's lying around on the classpath. It's much safer to load the processor you want explicitly: for example if you want Saxon Professional Edition, use `new com.saxonica.ProfessionalTransformerFactory()`.

Even better, rather than using JAXP, use Saxon's s9api interface which gives you much more control over how parameters are passed to the transformation.

Note also, the error relates to a call from the stylesheet to external Java methods. It has nothing to do with the subject of your question, which is passing parameters from the Java application into the XSLT code.